# When there is no entry in database, if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) returns true but also run the else part after finishing the "if" part

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I have a register page in my app, and while registering, i check if the name is already registered or not in firebase. And if the name is already present, I am getting the toast message("user already exist") as required, but if there is a new entry, I am able to register perfectly but I am also getting the toast message after registration.

**Please refer the below code:**

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registration");

mFirebaseDatabase.orderByChild("uname").
equalTo(name.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {            

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
                createUser(name.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(), 
                           designation.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(),
                           phone.getText().toString().trim(), 
                           email.getText().toString().trim(),
                           password.getText().toString().trim(),
                           email1.getText().toString().trim(),
                           phone1.getText().toString().trim(),
                           telephone.getText().toString().trim());
                 Intent login = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                 startActivity(login);
             }
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
 });
```

So After registration, I am getting the message "user already registered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you create new user and add to firebase database the `onDataChange` listener have been triggered one more time.

You can try this code maybe help you:

```
boolean isUserCreated = false;
mFirebaseDatabase....addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {            

@Override
public void onDataChange(...) {
    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userId)) {
            isUserCreated = true;
            createUser(...) 
         }
     } else if (!isUserCreated) {
         Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User already Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
... 
});
```

**Note:** This code is concise. You must notice to `isUserCreated` variable and usage of that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior.
From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write):

> Important: The onDataChange() method is called every time data is changed at the specified database reference, including changes to children. To limit the size of your snapshots, attach only at the highest level needed for watching changes. For example, attaching a listener to the root of your database is not recommended.

So the first time it checks the user is not there and therefore it creates it. But by creating it you’re probably pushing it to firebase which triggers the `onDataChanged` again and you see the toast.

If you want to execute it only one time **change `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`** (check specifically the section [Listen for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events))

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is that you are checking for the dataSnapshot.getValue() == null everytime

```
 @Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
  ....
 }else{
      Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User already Registered", 
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }
}
```

In this case what happens when you came for the first time there is no user data  dataSnapshot.getValue() was null and then you created a user using your method createUser() and just after you create your user firebase triggers a callback in your onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) method and this time dataSnapshot.getValue() is having your user data and the condition you are checking take control to else part and toast appears.

OnDataChanged is called every time you change a value in your firebase on that reference.

You need to change the if and else condition to check whether a user is registered or not if registered show a toast else register them.